# Harry Potter Fanfiction where Hermione and other students were captured

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I am looking for a Harry Potter fanfiction. I don't remember the title. I believe it was posted on fanfiction.net

Here is what I remember:

Hermione was captured during an attack on Hogwarts along with other students. Parvati and Lavender were also captured. The older girls were used as sex slaves/prostitutes for the Death Eaters. Hermione was inspected by Voldemort. Hermione had a spell placed on her to prevent her from crying. Lucius became obsessed with Hermione, made her take polyjuice and look like Narcissa.  Lucius placed a silver spiky ball in Hermione's body. Parvati ended up pregnant with Lestrange's child. Remus and Sirius appeared to betray the Order. Hermione's made to give Remus a blow job. Kingsley betrayed Hermione. He was the one who stunned Hermione in the back.

Comment: https://solveforum.com/forums/threads/solved-harry-potter-fanfiction-hermione-and-other-students-captured.527358/#login

Comment: "WHA???" is all I can say